# Creating Dynamic URLs Based on User Selection in WordPress Form

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-shortcode

I have created a database table and uploaded it to the WordPress database. On one page, I have created a form with two select options. When the user chooses different options and submits the form, the link will be created accordingly. For example, if the user selects "zerodha" and "5paisa," the link will be made as http://localhost/c/zerodha-vs-5paisa. Similarly, if the user selects "upstox" and "groww," the URL will change to http://localhost/c/upstox-vs-groww. The URL will change dynamically based on the user's selection.

Comment: You asked the same thing already not even a full day ago.